# The MDK-5 (Keil-5) cannot build my project!

Tags: compiler, keil

I'm trying to build my project but the MDK-5 give me this error:

[image: figure]

And also as you can see, in target you just can see Xtal.

What happened?

What's the problem?

Comment: Hi Roh, you might be best just to include the options as a screen shot and include the build output as text it's a bit hard to read. Putting the errors as text also makes it searchable for anyone with the same problem in the future.

Comment: The third line describes an error. There is a file that has a time stamp on it or in it that is in the future. The compiler either thinks there is an error in the file or it dismisses the need for compilation because the file is current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to my friends, jippie and PeterJ
I found the problem. the time and date of my PC had changed to past. I modified the time and the date and finally the keil works again.